# Displaying English on the right side of Chinese after click Chinese

Tags: javascript, html, css

After applying the given code, the 3 languages working without fail. But when we click the chinease language, English is displaying on the right side of Chinese. I just want to remove that.I have tried different ways but nothing is working. 
[image]

ENG | 中文 | 한국어

```
<div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function googleTranslateElementInit2() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: 'en',
      autoDisplay: false
    }, 'google_translate_element2');
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function GTranslateGetCurrentLang() {
    var keyValue = document['cookie'].match('(^|;) ?googtrans=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return keyValue ? keyValue[2].split('/')[2] : null;
  }

  function GTranslateFireEvent(element, event) {
    try {
      if (document.createEventObject) {
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        element.fireEvent('on' + event, evt)
      } else {
        var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt)
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  function doGTranslate(lang_pair) {
    if (lang_pair.value) lang_pair = lang_pair.value;
    if (lang_pair == '') return;
    var lang = lang_pair.split('|')[1];
    if (GTranslateGetCurrentLang() == null && lang == lang_pair.split('|')[0]) return;
    var teCombo;
    var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++)
      if (/goog-te-combo/.test(sel[i].className)) {
        teCombo = sel[i];
        break;
      }
    if (document.getElementById('google_translate_element2') == null || document.getElementById('google_translate_element2').innerHTML.length == 0 || teCombo.length == 0 || teCombo.innerHTML.length == 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        doGTranslate(lang_pair)
      }, 500)
    } else {
      teCombo.value = lang;
      GTranslateFireEvent(teCombo, 'change');
      GTranslateFireEvent(teCombo, 'change')
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't understand your question? What is your problem?

Comment: @kalido, after clicking the chinease language,   English is displaying on the right side of Chinese. I've attached the screenshot.

Comment: @ArpitJain, after clicking the Chinese language, English is displaying on the right side of Chinese. I've attached the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just because of the text that you gave inside the anchor tag. You can replace the text with the image.